# Unable to check mulitple files in "Manage Files with no checked in version" - SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, check-out, check-in

I am able to check in the files one at a time, but I should be able to choose multiple files by clicking the check box. Problem is...there are NO check boxes to click. Help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this feature is still not available in SharePoint online, under review/development: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13396893-bulk-check-in-check-out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no check boxes in “Manage Files with no checked in version” - SharePoint online

But you can check in multiple files from the document library, choose all files which need to be checked in, click "check in":

[image]